# Кириллица в PL/Python

Tags: python, postgresql, utf-8, python-2.x, кодировка

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь реализовать функцию на PL/Python(PostgreSQL 9.5, Python 2.7). Так вот никак не могу сработаться с кириллическими функциями. Ниже собственно код:

```
create or replace function pytest()
returns varchar
as
$$
  import os, pymorphy2

  morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()
  word = morph.parse(u'смартфоны')[0];
  #return word.word # Возвращает ñð¼ð°ñññð¾ð½ñ
  #return u'смартфоны' # Возвращает ÑÐ¼Ð°ÑÑÑÐ¾Ð½Ñ
  return 'смартфоны' # Возвращает смартфоны
$$ language plpython2u;
```

При этом и в repr().decode('unicode_escape') оборачивал, и вручную кодировал/декодировал. Все равно крякозябры, правда уже другие. При этом если загнать в переменную какой либо слово на кириллице, то выводится все норм. Может кто сталкивался? БД у меня в UTF8(en_US.UTF-8). В чем может быть проблема, ума ни приложу. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Кто вам посоветовал `sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')` использовать?

Comment: Искал уж в google. На stackoverflow и посоветовали. Даже если убрать это, все равно крякозябры.

Comment: можете ссылку конкретную привести. Если бы я думал, что это решит вашу проблему, я бы в качестве ответа, а не комментария писал. Для начала вы должны изолировать проблему--у вас слишком много частей: 1- работает ли `return u'смартфоны'`? Если работает, то чините pymorphy2 (вне pl/python).  Если не работает, то уберите из примера pymorphy2. 2- естественно уберите setdefaultencoding. Эта конструкция может скрывать проблемы. 3- не используйте`repr().decode('unicode_escape')`. Кракозябры указывают, что текст был перекодирован, используя несовместимую кодировку.

Comment: @jfs по поводу repr() мне посоветовали вот здесь http://python.su/forum/topic/31533/
По поводу setdefaultencoding - даже если убрать функцию, то все равно кракозябры. Видимо проблемы внутри pymorphy2, т.к. если просто return 'смартфоны', то все нормально возвращается.

Comment: ещё раз: `setdefaultencoding` вызов следует убрать вне зависимости от вашей текущей проблемы. Хотя его *отсутствие* может помочь в отладке как этой так и других проблем с текстом (и наоборот: его наличие может скрывать другие возможные проблемы--вы не думаете что у вас только один баг в программе?).

Comment: @jfs
Убрал setdefaultencoding, return 'смартфоны' возвращает корректно, а вот u'смартфоны' возвращают ÑÐ¼Ð°ÑÑÑÐ¾Ð½Ñ.
Вне pl/python собственно я получал то, что описал в топике на python.su

Comment: вся информация о вопросе должна быть здесь. Вместо комментария, отредактируйте ваш вопрос и явно приведите полный код (минимальный), который проблему вызывает. Не надо прыгать: у вас может быть несколько проблем, решайте одну за другой: попробуйте понять, что делаете. Не надо случайные фрагменты кода пробовать в надежде что что-то заработает.

Comment: 1- Я не знаю как мягко выразиться о `repr().decode('unicode-escape')`. Могу только порекомендовать выучить разницу между объектом и его текстовым представлением в Питоне. 2- если проблема внутри pymorphy2 и вы можете её воспроизвести вне pl/python, тогда именно эту проблему и надо сперва решить.

Comment: @jfs
Отредактировал вопрос. repr() по крайней мере решил проблему. Вне PL/Python все отрабатывает нормально.

Comment: топор решает проблему головной боли--навсегда. Это не значит, что его следует как лекарство использовать. repr() полезен **для/во время отладки**, а не для того чтобы проблемы с кодировкой в рабочем коде исправлять.

Comment: *"Вне PL/Python все отрабатывает нормально."* включите это в вопрос. Всё кроме `return u'смартфоны' # Возвращает ÑÐ¼Ð°ÑÑÑÐ¾Ð½Ñ` можно для начала убрать. Научитесь с Unicode работать в pl/python. Работает ли: `return u'\u0441\u043c\u0430\u0440\u0442\u0444\u043e\u043d\u044b'`?

Comment: @jfs Да, работает. Мб переместиться в чат? Если вам не трудно

Comment: чат автоматически предлагается системой (но у вас репутации не достаточно, чтобы в чате писать). Если `u'\u0441\u043c'` работает, а `u'см'` не работает, то проверьте что coding заголовок наверху файла содержит фактическую кодировку, если этот код в файле лежит. Если написано: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`, то исходный код следует сохранять как utf-8, а не cp1251 итд.

Comment: @jfs
Я пишу все это в pgAdmin4. Кодинг заголовок также не решает проблему. Прбовал .decode('base64'), т.к. в доках встречается упоминание, но все равно.

Comment: Если вы не знаете какую кодировку использует pgAdmin4, тогда вводите все константы как ascii: `u'\u0441\u043c'`. Или узнайте в какой кодировке pgAdmin4 сохраняет текст скрипта. Часто вам руками строковые константы с не-ascii символами надо вводить? Естественно, это никак не влияет на строки из других источников (из файла, сети, базы, итд)--вы должны узнавать какую кодировку использует каждый источник и превращать в Unicode на границе с вашей программой (например: `unicode_text = bytestring.decode(character_encoding)`).

Comment: @jfs
Заработало, обновил вопрос.

Comment: не помещайте решение (ответ) в вопрос. Опубликуйте как свой ответ—[это явно поощряется](https://goo.gl/p3McsM). Для констант в тексте программы, возможно pl/python работает как python 2.1 до pep 263 (до 2001 кода--15 лет назад): юникодные константы интерпретируются как latin-1. То есть ваше окружение (pgAdmin) может корректно передавать символы, используя utf-8 кодировку, а pl/python как latin-1 декодирует. (в обычном питоне) `print(u'смартфоны'.encode('utf-8').decode('latin-1'))` -> `ÑÐ¼Ð°ÑÑÑ
           Ð¾Ð½Ñ`  Чтобы исправить: `mojibake.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')`

Comment: возможно вместо жёстко прописанного utf-8, посмотрите на `plpy.execute("SHOW client_encoding", 1)[0]["client_encoding"]` (или `server_encoding`)

Comment: @jfs
Огромное спасибо вам за помощь. Я непременно проверю, то что вы написали.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так скрипт заработал и в PL/Python и вне PL/Python.

```
create or replace function pytest(p_word varchar)
returns varchar
as
$$
  import os, pymorphy2

  morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()
  word = morph.parse(p_word.decode('utf-8'))[0];
  return word.normal_form
  #word.inflect({'gent'})
$$ language plpython2u;
```